# Having trouble with reactive and leafletProxy, observe function in Rshiny when creating leaflet application

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, reactive

Using forms of if statements, observe and leafletProxy, but I can't seem to get it working. I have two seperate database one of them is *PLOT* and the other one is *ISTANBUL_OIM*. *PLOT* has longitude, latitude, *KUME_NO* and *ENV_YILI*. KUME_NO is basically sample plot number and *ENV_YILI* is the year of inventory collection. *ISTANBUL_OIM* is also the border of Forestry Districts as multiple polygons.

Basically, I want to make two conditions which are based on sample plot number (**KUME_NO**) as a dropdown menu and group check box menu based on inventory year (**ENV_YILI**), and then if I select a particular condition my leaflet map to zoom to selected both **KUME_NO** number and **ENV_YILI** according to the inputs.

[You can find the database](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LVvcLg2whVjhOAHU_maCohnNQE6j8aFc?usp=drive_link)

[Image 1: the interface I want to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiS6X.jpg)

[Image 2: zoom according to the condition I want to put in my interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPBt2.jpg)

I wanted to start with at least running ***KUME_NO*** condition but I get this error: **Warning: Error in resolveFormula: argument "data" is missing, with no default.**

[Here is my app R code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1pORe-C_i9kMOnpfJgP6gK1IBTrJ5k6mV/view?usp=drive_link)

Sorry I can't copy the code chunk here because I get a *Your question appears to be spam*. warning, so I'm sharing the app.R app directly via google drive link.

Comment: It's not acceptable to provide a link to your code. You should edit your question and provide a [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The `system.reactive` tag is for Microsoft's Reactive Framework. It does not belong here.